# Css, sprites animation

Tags: css, animation, sprite

I have 5 png images (hippo doing press-ups!) that I want to animate on mouseover on a site. I have managed to animate them using a sprite and css positioning but,
a) I don't know how to stop and start the animation on mouseover/mouseoff and...
b) it doesn't work in IE
Help please
http://www.arc-bpictures.com/anim.html
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just move your #sprite animation rules to `#sprite:hover`.

```
#sprite {
    width:197px;
    height:250px;
    background:url(img/anim1.png) 0 0;
}

#sprite:hover {
    -webkit-animation-duration:1200ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:step-start;
    -webkit-animation-name:animate01;
    -moz-animation-duration:1200ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:step-start;
    -moz-animation-name:animate01;
}
```

Oh, and no css that starts with `-webkit-` or `-moz-` is going to work in IE. For IE < 9 you would need to use javascript to achieve this (not sure about IE9's animated CSS support).

Comment: Thanks very much for that. Can you suggest what I could do to allow it to work in IE? Thanks anyway

Comment: I'm afraid not. My javascript skills are ok, but I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: Ok, no problem - could you just help me with something else please - I want the animation to just run once on mouseover. How do I change the code:-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite; What instead of infinite? Thanks

Comment: Actually I answered my own question - once! Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. If you think it was a good answer an upvote would be appreciated. If you think it answered your question than accepting it would be good too ;)

Comment: Sorry, first time using this - how do I do what you asked ?

Comment: Cheers for accepting. You click on the up arrow to upvote, down arrow to downvote http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the IE css issue so I've threw a light jQuery plugin together which will do the job I think.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QHnrv/3/)

```
(function($)
{
    var p = {
        imgObj: false,
        timeout:1000,
        images:[0,0,0,0],
        index: -1
    }
    function next()
    {
        if(p.index >= p.images.length -2)
            p.index = 0;
        else
            p.index++;
        /*Update image source*/
        $(p.imgObj).attr("src",p.images[p.index]);
    }

    /*Sprite
      Turn an img element into an animated sprite
      - Call on html img object
      params:
        timeout = duration between changes
        images = Array of image sources
        index = Starting index for images, returns to zero if greater than image count
    */
    $.fn.sprite = function(params)
    {
        p.imgObj = this;
        if(params)
            p = $.extend(true,p, params);
        /*Initiate image iteration*/
        setInterval(next,p.timeout);     
    }

})(jQuery);

/*Example:*/
var params = {
    images:["http://www.english4today.com/i/element_test48.gif",
            "http://www.web2access.org.uk/images/oxygen_test.png",
            "https://www.uk.etsglobal.org/store/images/cache/11_UK_logo_test_ico_tests2.jpg?1212756259"]};

/*Attach plugin*/
$("#test").sprite(params);
```